# Good mongodb configuration

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have been playing with PHP & mySQL for a while now, as I stumbled on a problem anyone will eventually get: Scaling.

After some research I found about mongoDB, which seems a pretty good option for an easily scalable database. Now, I have read the manual on their official webste, but as a total newbie on mongo, I can easily follow the instruction to create a *single* node server, but would like to know better how to build mongo clusters,

do you know any documents regarding installation & configuration on a multiple nodes environment, such as EC2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scalability usually is the result of a **good design** rather than the choice of technology.

Comment: I know mysql has been out there for so long but "new" does not necessarily means "worse"... it might be worth a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running on EC2 10gen recommends using a raid 10 setup for storage and having enough memory on your instances to contain your working set of data. I will provide some links on good places to start gathering information.

To scale reads you need to create replica sets:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets

Then, when you need to scale writes, learn about sharding:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction

However, be aware that there are performance limits related to the maximum throughput of ebs on ec2.